# Cannot display this video mode on boot

Tags: 12.04, display, display-resolution, edubuntu

I have googled around, but nobody seems to have found a solution for this problem.

This computer will not boot to Linux cds, so i have installed ubuntu on a hard drive and then put the hard drive in the computer. When I boot the computer (after POST) it runs through this: (clean install btw)

monitor immediately displays message saying cannot display this video mode (presumably when splash screen should display)

~40 seconds later displays grey screen with cursor (this usually displays right before showing desktop)

~5 seconds later displays cannot display video mode error

~3 seconds later message disappears and monitor turns on and off back light infinatlely (shows up as screen appearing to cycle shades of black)

A video of the boot activity is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9T6WEMX5BMU)

interestingly when the power button is pressed, the system shuts off about 10 seconds later. It's not an instant shutdown which would indicate the system not responding, but it's not the 60 seconds that would indicate the desktop is running and the timeout has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, issue resolved. Long story short several days later: The onboard video card wouldn't work under any circumstances. Adding a pci card and using nomodeset works. I also had to change out the power supply as it was causing hard drive issues. Nomodeset also allows the computer to boot to linux cds.